# How to design code around disjoint types that share similar behavior?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator, strategy-pattern

**Premise**

Existing codebase (not likely to change):

```
public interface Shape {
  void print();
}
```

And with the implementations such as (Circle, Triangle, Square, etc):

```
public final class Circle implements Shape {

  private final CircleInput input;

  public Circle(CircleInput input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  @Override
  public void print() { ... }
}
```

`CircleInput`, `TriangleInput`, and `SquareInput` are NOT related at all (disjoint types).

**Problem**

**Input objects can be very complex and I want users to create a class that encapsulates their own business logic.** I explored two approaches, but they were both clunky and that leads me to think if I am approaching the problem incorrectly and there is a better way to use Java.

**Option 1**

I thought about defining a generic interface:

```
public interface ShapeInput<T> {
  T getInput();
}
```

User can then create:

```
public final class MyCircleInput<CircleInput> {

  private final ShapeDependency shapeDependency;

  @Inject
  MyCircleInput(ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
    this.shapeDependency = shapeDependency;
  }

  @Override
  public CircleInput getInput() {
    return createCircleInput(shapeDependency);
  }

  // ... very complex business logic ...
  private static CircleInput createCircleInput(
      ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
    // returns a CircleInput
  }
}
```

then use a ShapeFactory to create the correct instance based on type. But I am unable to say `ShapeInput<CircleInput | TriangleInput>` and enforcing this behavior requires runtime checks.

**Option 2**

I could use inheritance on `Shape` directly:

```
public abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {

  protected final Shape shapeImpl;

  public AbstractShape(CircleInput input) {
    this.shapeImpl = new Circle(input);
  }

  public AbstractShape(TriangleInput input) {
    this.shapeImpl = new Triangle(input);
  }

  // Proxies print() to the underlying impl.
  @Override
  public void print() {
    return shapeImpl.print();
  }
}
```

and users can create:

```
public final MyCircle extends AbstractShape {

  @Inject
  MyCircle(ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
    super(createCircleInput(shapeDependency));
  }

  // ... very complex business logic ...
  private static CircleInput createCircleInput(
      ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
    // returns a CircleInput
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a more-real example, it's kind of hard to get a context with just a bunch of "Things". Also `public ThingBInput getInput() {return createThingAInput(thingDep);}` wouldn't compile, I assume you mean `createThingBInput`.

Comment: You basically want the correct "Thing" implementation to be chosen based on what "ThingInput" is passed in?

Comment: Yup! That's the intention. The requirement being the user needs to encode this in a class somewhere. The framework will take this class and lazily instantiate the correct "Thing".

Comment: Let me revisit the examples and make them less abstract

Comment: Fixed the typo and used real world objects to better describe the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The business logic should create the input objects?

Comment: @DON'TPANIC The example code provided by you is really confusing. `AbstractShape`  has constructors that take `CircleInput` or `TriangleInput` but subclasses only care about one shape (For example : `MyCircle` only really care about a Circle and not a Triangle.)

Answer (score 0):

So `Circle`, `Square`, `Triangle` (which are all `Shape`s) and their respective inputs `CircleInput`, `SquareInput`, and `TriangleInput` (which are disjoint) are already well-defined in this system?

Why should the users extend any of these inputs at all?

Isn't your pipeline essentially that a `ShapeDependency` is acted upon by some business logic to create `ShapeInput` and pass it to the correct `Shape`?

You could clarify this by clearly defining the responsibility of each class. I would expect the sole responsibility of `CircleInput`, `SquareInput` etc would be to just hold input data, *not* to perform business logic.

I would keep that business logic in its own class, maybe something like this:

```
abstract class BusinessLogic<S extends Shape, I> {
    private final Function<I, S> shapeConstructor;

    public BusinessLogic(Function<I, S> shapeConstructor) {
        this.shapeConstructor = shapeConstructor;
    }

    protected abstract I createShapeInput(ShapeDependency shapeDependency);

    public final S createShape(ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
        I shapeInput = createShapeInput(shapeDependency);
        S shape = shapeConstructor.apply(shapeInput);
        return shape;
    }
}

class CircleBusinessLogic extends BusinessLogic<Circle, CircleInput> {

    public CircleBusinessLogic() {
        super(Circle::new);
    }

    @Override
    protected CircleInput createShapeInput(ShapeDependency shapeDependency) {
        return new CircleInput();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this satisfies your requirements. If not, please clarify your goals and pipeline.